# Element not found (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490) while calling BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync()

Tags: c#, background, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

While trying to get the lockscreenaccessstatus by calling `BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync()`on the very first launch of my WinRT app,  I am getting this exception:

```
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)
```

Weirdly, this issue is no more happening on the second (and subsequent) launch of the app.

I read that as a workaround we can introduce a `Task.Delay(1000)` just before calling the `BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync()`. But, it does not seem to be working for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I finally was able to figure out the workaround. I moved the code to prompt the user `BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync()` to a later stage, i.e. when I have loaded my first VM. It all works fine now.

Comment: what does this mean - "when I have loaded my first VM"? I'm getting the same exception in background task on Windows 8.1, while it works on Windows Phone 8.1